# Run realm with android experimental plugin

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, realm

Is there a way to use Realm with the latest Android experimental plugin for Gradle:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental ?

Here is an error message, which I've got during application build:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'realm-android']
   > 'com.android.application' or 'com.android.library' plugin required.
```

I'm interested in Realm, but I need to use experimental plugin because of its NDK support the same time.

Comment: Did some testing but it seems we have some further dependencies need to be fixed. See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2539.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update Android Studio to 2.2 resolved the problem.

"There are other choices now like the the ndk with cmake which doesn't require the experimental plugin https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master-cmake/hello-jni ."

[found here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2539)